# i have -multiselect-dropdown , and all i need is send my value when put request into backend , but i cant catch value

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material, multi-select

```
     <ng-multiselect-dropdown
              class="col-4 ng2-select-dropdown"
              [placeholder]="'Select Tags'"
              formControlName="tags"
              id="select_tags"
              [settings]="dropdownTagsSettings"
              [data]="tagsList"
              (onSelect)="onItemSelectTags($event)"
            >
            </ng-multiselect-dropdown>

            <ng-multiselect-dropdown
              class="col-4 ng2-select-dropdown"
              [placeholder]="'Select Stores '"
              [settings]="dropdownStoreSettings"
              [data]="myStores"
              formControlName="stores"
              (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
              (selectionChange)="changeSelectedStores()"
            >
            </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

value is id , when i select item i pushing this id into array , but when i unselect same item , the id still exist inside array

Comment: show your onItemSelect function and also check if any event available when item is deselect in ng-multiselect-dropdown, check the documentation.

Comment: onItemSelect(item: any) {
    this.storeSelectedData.push(item.id);
      
  }
and there is no any option for deselecting items

Answer (score 0):

add  (onDeSelect)="onDeSelect($event)" event in html for ng-multiselect-dropdown and in component.ts and the below method to delete item from array

```
public onDeSelect(item: any) 
{
    console.log(item);
    this.storeSelectedData.forEach((element, index) => 
    {
      this.storeSelectedData.forEach((element, index) => {
         if (element == item.id) 
          delete this.storeSelectedData[index];});
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text inside of a `code` block and not as an image. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)